# ¿Recomendar a los nuevos usuarios que vayan al chat?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Como es natural, hay muchos usuarios que no conocen la mecánica del sitio o que simplemente aún no han desarrollado buenas estrategias de resolución de problemas. Normalmente formulan una pregunta muy mala, reciben votos negativos, algún comentario y no vuelven más. ¿Podríamos recomendarles que se pasaran por el chat para recibir orientación o consejos? También incluir un enlace directo a la sala no vendría mal:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

¿Qué opina la comunidad de esto?

Comment: Tener en cuenta que se necesita 20 de reputación mínimo para poder participar en el chat.  http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Por cierto, esta duda ya fue planteada en Stack Exchange http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat

Comment: @astrojuanlu El origen de la duda que pones es otro. Recuerda que hay un chat general y que se puede abrir un chat para una pregunta específica. El link que pones se basa en el argumento de que cuando un usuario nuevo hace una pregunta generalmente hacen falta muchos comentarios para orientarlo y que el sitio comenzará a decirte que lo muevas a un chat pero esto no es posible si el usuario es de baja reputación sin la intervanción de un moderador. La idea planteada ahí es que el sitio permita el chat basandose en la reputacion del que invita no en la del que hace la pregunta.

Comment: Me parece una buena idea, pero por la reputación necesaria para entrar al chat, de repente los nuevos usuarios no llegarian a ese valor, porque al hacer mal sus preguntas estarían obteniendo puntos en contra y no sumarian en positivo, dificilmente llegarian a 20.

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios Esto no es del todo cierto porque aún recuerdo que mi primer pregunta en SO en ingles me costó 5 votos negativos y la medalla [presión de pares](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure). Actualmente hay 2 otorgadas y los usuarios pasan de 20 puntos. Pasar de ahí es fácil cuando haces buenas preguntas e investigas antes. Creo que subir de reputación es mucho mas dificil en el sitio en inglés que aquí porque mucho de lo que se pregunta allá por usuarios nuevos es marcado como duplicado. Mira las preguntas para que veas que no hay tantos votos negativos.

Comment: @devconcept Ah perfecto, de repente interprete mal las pautas sobre la acumulación de puntos. Si las cosas son como mencionas, las nuevas participaciones podrían ganar los puntos necesarios para poder usar el chat, por ende, se podrían promocionar los diferentes canales y así lograr mayor cantidad de participantes, para que compartan sus experiencias y problemáticas.

Answer (score 3):

Esto es una buena idea siempre que se consideren algunas cosas.

Los usuarios necesitan al menos 20 puntos de reputación para poder participar en el chat por lo que no va a ser una opción para algunos pero muchos de los usuarios que aún no tienen participación regular en el sitio que tengan suficiente reputación pueden conocer mejor la comunidad y llegar a identificarse con ella.

Es importante que los usuarios nuevos comprendan que el chat es un lugar para relajarse, compartir y hablar de temas que no corresponden con el formato de *Preguntas y Respuestas*, no para resolver los problemas del día a día. La razón de mayor peso aquí es que el conocimiento que se comparta en el chat no será fácilmente localizable por los que vengan después, no afecta la reputación y limita la solución a los que están conectados en ese momento. Es muy difícil hablar de un tema que se vió cerrado tres días atrás mientras que en el sitio principal se pueden lograr dos medallas por esto [resurgimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival) y [nigromante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) lo cual implica que una buena respuesta siempre es bien recibida sin importar el momento en que se escriba.

La parte buena del asunto es puede aumentar la calidad de las preguntas y respuestas porque los usuarios sabrán como formularlas mejor y reduce la posibilidad de que eliminen sus cuentas porque sus preguntas fueron recibidas negativamente. Nosotros deberíamos hacerlos sentir a gusto sin sacrificar la calidad de nuestro sitio. Ambas cosas son importantes y deberían cuidarse por igual.

Comment: Lo de que "el chat es un lugar para relajarse" la verdad es que no lo tengo claro - sí que es cierto que nuestro chat _hoy día_ es para eso, pero no he encontrado en la FAQ o en meta.stackoverflow.com referencias a esto. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @astrojuanlu Tenemos el poder y la opción de convertir nuestro chat a lo que se necesite en ese momento.  Si por ahora es mejor tener un lugar relajante para charlar, no hay problema.  Si en un futuro decidimos que el chat necesita ser algo mas profesional, igual lo podemos modificar.  Recuerda que nuestro sitio es nuestro lugar y no todo será igual que en el sitio de inglés.

Comment: @astrojuanlu Mi afirmación es más una recomendación que una obligación. Como dice Juan M que no existe una regla escrita para esto. Escribo pensando en que los programadores de habla hispana puedan beneficiarse de ese conocimiento. Vertir todo esto en el chat no ayuda a la causa y recuerda que hay personas que pueden tener las mismas dudas que tú o que se pueden beneficiar de lo que sabes. Si puedes decirle a un usuario "escribeme eso como una pregunta en el sitio que enseguida te la respondo" todos se benefician. Recuerda que el chat **es una extensión** del sitio, no un sustituto para él.

Comment: Precisamente @devconcept se trata de hablar en el chat las preguntas de las cuales **no** puede beneficiarse toda la comunidad porque no están claras, bien formuladas o les falta información. Se trata de instruir a los usuarios nuevos a que hagan preguntas útiles. no a sustituir el sitio - tal y como dije en mi pregunta original.