# Usar el chat como aula para aprender en grupo

Tags: discusión, enseñanza-aprendizaje

Quiero plantearles una idea (gracias a @Fredyfx, @LuiggiMendoza, y @astrojuanlu por sus ideas) que pienso que sera una gran manera de poder seguir ayudando a nuestros usuarios.

La idea es de abrir una sala de chat para tratar un tema en especifico donde se puede aprender, compartir y preguntar. Un ejemplo seria:

**"Como crear tu primer 'Hola, Mundo' en Godot."**

Se abriría la sala en un día especifico y el líder de la discusión tomaría su puesto para moderar la platica, clase, o sesión. Otras charlas se pueden fijar en el calendario y así tendremos varias para escoger y asistir.

¿Que les parece? De aquí, se necesitaría empezar a juntar los nombres de los individuales que les interese ser líder o moderador de estas tecnologías.  Si la idea les interesa, podremos añadir los requisitos de los líderes en un futuro.

Si te interesa ser parte de este proyecto como un líder/moderador, favor de seguir este enlace:

**[¿Te interesa ser líder/moderador de una tecnología para las charlas de Stack Overflow en español?](http://goo.gl/forms/F2ncBXk6y9)**

Comment: Yo apoyo esta idea y tal vez me ofrezca de mentor o busque alguno :)

Comment: Excelente, apoyo la idea totalmente!

Answer (score 4):

Está muy buena la idea, me gusta. De esta forma, creo que se va a poder aprender mucho. Like

Answer (score 4):

> Quiero plantearles una idea (gracias a @Fredyfx, @LuiggiMendoza, y @astrojuanlu por sus ideas) que pienso que sera una gran manera de poder seguir ayudando a nuestros usuarios.

A modo de historia, la ayuda de @fredyx y @astrojuanlu proviene de estas preguntas en meta que ellos realizaron:

> [Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/496/227)
>
> [¿Recomendar a los nuevos usuarios que vayan al chat?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/552/227)

Y que vi que se podían realizar al mismo tiempo utilizando el chat, tal como pueden revisarlo en [esta sala](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38983/servlets-e-intro-a-java-ee) donde platicamos sobre un tema en particular (en el caso de la sala, el tema es Servlets e Introducción a Java EE).

La iniciativa viene de la comunidad y su rumbo va acorde a las ideas que hay en la comunidad. Les pido por favor que continúen participando y expongan más ideas que nos ayuden a madurar el concepto mediante respuestas a esta pregunta y comentarios. Asimismo, están invitados a la [sala de chat del sitio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde también sus ideas son bienvenidas.

Answer (score 3):

definitivamente me agrada! me apunto! Quienes le quieran ir con C#, Web y la onda Microsoft, vamos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: Yo también me apunto para todo lo que tenga que ver con .net

Comment: hey @CarlosMuñoz, te parece si le vamos al C# como 'mentores' de quienes se apunten a aprender con nosotros #HablaVas!

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo

Comment: Todo lo que sea VS, C# y el resto de cosas de Microsoft, aquí me tienen listo para aprender y colaborar en lo que se pueda

Comment: y se armó el equipo! Gracias @JuanManuelPalacios, el siguiente paso es hacer la convocatoria con una fecha limite de tiempo (2 semanas les suena bien?), acordamos una fecha para lanzar todas las ideas de lo que podremos hacer, coordinamos las reuniones online y le damos play al proyecto con todo el power! #HablaVas! #MotivacionAFull :D

Comment: Buen dia, quisiera consultar sobre los novatos como yo, interesados en .net, como podriamos estar atento a sus charlas, etc.

Comment: @Miko, ya estaremos dando a conocer mayores detalles conforme se compilen las ideas :D

Answer (score 3):

Me parece genial la idea.

Particularmente creo que puedo empezar a apoyar con `C#`  a nivel de lenguaje.
Tal vez luego podría tomar nuevos temas

Answer (score 3):

Excelente idea, así las personas interesadas podrán ir al tema que consideren adecuado de manera directa y podran aprender lo que realmente necesitan, y si después de eso vienen más dudas y/o otros temas se podrían empezar a programar sesiones que aborden esos puntos. Por ejemplo, a mi me interesa mucho aprender PHP y programación Web con ASP, HTML y algunas otras cosas más, tener a alguien que haga de mentor me parece genial. Gracias por compartir, ahora solo queda esperar que se concreten.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece una excelente idea! 
Las preguntas buenas que surjan de esos cursos deberían crearse en SOes así quedan disponibles para toda la comunidad ya que tal vez alguno se pierde esas charlas.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece una excelente idea, ademas las preguntas interesantes que se puedan generar en estas salas de aprendizaje se pueden compartir en la la plataforma principal, de manera que crece la plataforma y las personas que están involucradas en los temas a tratar.

Answer (score 1):

Es una excelente idea, de verdad que esto también ayudaría a crecer la comunidad de una u otra forma, ya que muchas personas que desconocen el chat empezarían a integrarse mas ha menudo, y la difusión de esta seria mayor.

Answer (score 0):

Luego que no tengo mucha experiencia en la programacion me gustaria paraticipar para aprender y ganar mas experiencia.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también me apunto. Ya llene el formulario. :P